# Building NLua from source (Windows): Lua52.dll?

Tags: building, nlua

I'm struggling with building NLua from source on Windows. 
It requires a modified Lua version, otherwise my code fails with a missing "lua52.dll".
https://github.com/NLua/NLua/issues/53

I tried to get it from here
https://github.com/NLua/lua
then used "cmake ." and built the resulting "lua.sln" in visual studio.

What happens is that I get a "lua52d.dll" (note the "d"). If I rename it, a "System.BadImageFormatException" is thrown by "KeraLua" (when I try with some "NLua.exe" executable I found in the "tests" folder of NLua).

Can anybody tell me how to build the modified lua52.dll required by NLua? 
I already have a binary that works but need to be able to rebuild everything by myself. Possibly I'm simply using the wrong source tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the right source tree, its just that you're compiling the *debug* version of the dll, not the *release* version of the dll. The added 'd' is to denote that it is the *debug* version of the dll, not the *release* version.

Comment: Thanks, switched to "Release" and the "d" is gone. There was one (unrelated) problem with the latest version: lua's _G.unpack has moved into table.unpack, and the exception handler uses it. An "_G.unpack=table.unpack" as first line seems to fix it.